# netcat from behind NAT

Tags: networking

I have a device connected to the internet, but it is behind a NAT, meaning that I cannot ssh directly into it from outside of the network. I have already figured out that reverse SSH tunneling can circumvent this issue.

Now I want to run a netcat server process on this device, accessible once again from outside of the network. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to figure this out on my own. It seems that ssh tunneling is basically port forwarding. I ran the following code on the server behind the NAT

```
ssh -N -R 4321:localhost:1234 user@client &
```

this sets up the tunnel that routes traffic from `client:4321` to `server:1234`, with the `&` to run it in the background. Still on the server, I then ran:

```
ncat -lk -c "python myscript.py" localhost 1234 &
```

which starts netcat process running `myscript.py`. Now I can connect to the server from my client via netcat

```
nc localhost 4321
```

(I didn't have `ncat` on my client but `nc` worked as well. My actual use case was to use the `socket` library in python to connect, which worked the same)